# Placing a searchbar in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to put a search-bar in my first app. I already searched about this topic and all that I found had an array as a constant, but I am using json.

```
import SwiftUI
let menu = Bundle.main.decode([MenuSection].self, from: "menu.json")

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buscar: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                List  {
                    ForEach(menu) { section in
                        Section(header: Busqueda(text: self.$buscar)) {
                            ForEach(section.items) {item in
                                detalleLinea(item: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Menu de opciones")
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I already tried different things, but none of it helped. `Section(header: Busqueda(text: self.$buscar))` had the searchbar and works fine - I can see it in my app, but I want to apply the filter in the `ForEach` inside

```
ForEach(section.items) {item in
    detalleLinea(item: item)
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Please don't post screenshot of your code, please add the code in your question instead.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve (where do you want to put the search bar?) and what hinders you from doing this (is it not showing? you don't know where to look for the documentation? is there a compiler error?). Your code does not contain any line where you would try to insert the bar. Please be more precise.

Comment: in this line i had the searchbar, and apears where i want

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012540/ios-swiftui-searchbar-and-rest-api

Comment: it is solved .. like this, thank you all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it solved thank you for help LuLuGaGa and all

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var buscar: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Busqueda(text: $buscar)
                List(menu.filter {
                    buscar.isEmpty ?
                        true :
                        "\($0)".localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(buscar)
                }, id: \.self) { item in
                    //                    ForEach(menu) {item1 in
                    detalleLinea(item: item)
                    //                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Menu de opciones")
            //                 .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```